# Fetch hi res images from reddit

Tags: javascript, json, api, reddit

I'm trying to fetch the hi res images from a subreddit by recency. I can pull the thumbnails but can't figure out how to pull the real hi res images.

Here's my code:

```
fetch('https://www.reddit.com/r/cats.json')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => res.data.children)
  .then(res => res.map(post => ({
    author: post.data.author,
    link: post.data.url,
    img: post.data.thumbnail,
    title: post.data.title
  })))
  .then(res => res.map(render))
  .then(res => console.log(res))

const app = document.querySelector('#app');

const render = post => {
  const node = document.createElement('div');
  node.innerHTML = `
      <a href="${post.link}">
        <img src="${post.img}"/>
      </a>`;
  app.appendChild(node);
}
```

& here's my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qt7ktv4L/1/)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to swap around your href and img src

```
fetch('https://www.reddit.com/r/cats.json')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => res.data.children)
.then(res => res.map(post => ({
  author: post.data.author,
  link: post.data.url,
  img: post.data.thumbnail,
  title: post.data.title
})))
.then(res => res.map(render))
.then(res => console.log(res))

const app = document.querySelector('#app');
const render = post => {
const node = document.createElement('div');
 node.innerHTML = `
  <a href="${post.img}">
    <img src="${post.link}"/>
  </a>`;
app.appendChild(node);
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qt7ktv4L/2/

Comment: do you know if it's possible to kill the broken links? The imgs that resolve to an icon instead of a photo?